# Represent an open set in terms of countable union of closed balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that for any open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, and $\delta>0$, there exists a countable collection $\mathcal{G}$ of disjoint closed balls in $U$ such that diam $\mathrm{B} \leq \delta$ for all $B \in \mathcal{G}$, and
\begin{align*}
  m\left(U \backslash \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{G}} B\right)=0
 \end{align*}

I know that for a measurable open set $U$, there exists a closed set $F\subset U$ such that $m(U\setminus F)\leq \epsilon$. Then I can have a sequence of closed sets $F_{n}$ such that $m(U\setminus F_{n})\leq 1/n$. If $F=\bigcup F_{n}$, then $m(U\setminus F)\leq 1/n$, which means it converges to $0$. I wonder how to fit $\delta$ into this argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will work (a familiar technique in topological measure theory):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all families of pairwise disjoint closed balls of radius $\le \delta$ and whose union sits inside $U$. It's clear this is a partially ordered set (by inclusion), non-empty (as $U$ is open) and that a union of a chain is an upper bound for that chain. SO Zorn applies and we take $\mathcal{G}$ to be a maximal element. It's automatically countable as $\Bbb R^n$ is ccc (even second countable).

I think this $\mathcal{G}$ is as required. It's clear that $U \setminus \bigcup \mathcal G$ does not contain a non-empty open set any more (it's nowhere dense) by maximality. We'll need a more Euclidean specific argument as to why the Lebesgue measure is $0$ I think.